# Multiple slideUp and slideDown with vBulletin

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, vbulletin, slideup

I'm trying to get this to work with vBulletin:
http://jsfiddle.net/amosrivera/AYWku/

It ONLY works for the FIRST POSTER of the thread and everybody else who replies on that thread, it will not work for. If they go make a thread and are the first poster, it works.

Comment: Glad to see that my custom mod is getting recognised around the vBulletin community. Did you manage to get something like my mod working in the end?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the html to use classes instead of id. I updated your example.
http://jsfiddle.net/AYWku/480/

Comment: Doesn't work. The CSS still functions just fine. The button on vBulletin simply doesn't react.

Comment: You might want to post example of the code with multiple instances of threads or provide a link which has that. Based on your example, I updated the code that would work with multiple buttons and threads. If you click on buttons they do hide and show the individual content elements. May be I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: http://vbulletin-mods.co.uk/forum/news-announcements/2015-using-multiple-accounts.html

Check his "My Statistics" button. It works for multiple people at the same time.

Comment: The page that your provided only has one post, no replies. Is this a good example of a post with replies? https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php/407953-Jira-login?p=2341286&mode=linear#post2341286

Comment: http://vbulletin-mods.co.uk/forum/news-announcements/1961-new-skin-report-bugs-suggestions-here-please.html

... it isn't that difficult to go to a different thread

Comment: Ok. So where will the button go? In each of the boxes next to div with class "content"?

Comment: One button goes inside a box. The button in a box is pressed, the rest of the boxes appear. When a person is done viewing the boxes, they press the button again, and the boxes go back to where they started.

Comment: The postrow class isn't defined either. Its just there but isn't defined by anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a mod made by tempus from that uk forum!

It's a mod on vb.org, search vb.org and you'll find your answer!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! I dunno if your answer helps but you could at least provide more info about it like pointing some links